# SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when upgrading to NewRelic version 9

Tags: node.js, typescript, syntax-error, newrelic

I have a few services which encounter this error after I upgrade the NewRelic agent to version 9+, no such error appears in NewRelic version 8.
One of the services is running on Node 14 the other on 16, both with Typescript 4.9.5.

```
node_modules/newrelic/lib/config/index.js:1124
  const inputEnabled = inputConfig?.logging?.enabled
                                   ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Please advise what causes this issue.

Comment: Optional chaining should be available in Node 14.

Comment: If you are on the right versions of node, it might be an encoding issue. Are you mixing windows and other platforms?

Comment: @Matt running on Mac os, the error happens also when running the services in Docker

Comment: Sounds normal. Could the docker services throwing the error be sharing the macos copy of `node_modules` though?   It looks like node might not be reading that `.` as a `.` but the character seems fine in what has been pasted.

Comment: Try a `rm -rf node_modules` and reinstall in the project. A different minor version of newrelic.  And a minimal `node test.js` just loading newrelic.  Might narrow it down.

Comment: @Matt, the issue is from the esm package. When I remove it, I no longer get this error, but I do get `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module node` on the import of the newrelic module, `import 'newrelic'`
Trying to figure out how to resolve

Comment: @DavidFaizulaev Did find any solution? I'm facing the same issue with newrelic upgrade. can you please update the solution here if you were able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

`"esm": "npm:esm-wallaby@^3.2.26"` adding this package.json and adding `require('newrelic')` before loading require('esm') worked for me.